# Force (linear and rotation) field between two magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, torque

Say I have the magnetic field of two magnets $S_1$ and $S_2$ as well as their respective magnetic moments. Each of their field strengths is modeled by a series of vortexes on a 2d plane. What is the total force acting on each of the two magnets (direction and amount) based on their strength and moment (algorithmic explanation without many complicated math symbols)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each atomic dipole in one magnet is subject to a torque which depends on it position and orientation in the field of the other magnet. Also, each dipole is subject to a force which depends on the gradient of the field from the other magnet.  For purposes of calculation, of its field or response to an external field, a magnet can be approximated by a solenoid of the same size, shape, and dipole moment. Numeric integration can give the field at any point near a current carrying solenoid.  Then you can find the force and torque on a current segment at that point.  With a large separation, you can treat each magnet as a dipole.